# How to prevent user from selecting jpeg or png types from file explorer

Tags: android

I am trying to make intent enables the user to select only text-type files such as pdf, doc or docx, i know there are multiple questions asking about that but all the 'verified' answers don't solve my problem,the intent indeed enables the user to select pdf and word files but also it enables him to select images ! that's the code i am using

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("text/plain");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"ChooseFile"),BookDialog.ChooseFile);
```

these the codes i tried

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("application/pdf"); 
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"ChooseFile"),BookDialog.ChooseFile);
```

attempt 3

```
String[] mimeTypes =
    {"application/msword","application/vnd.openxmlformats- officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", // .doc & .docx
                "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation", // .ppt & .pptx
                "application/vnd.ms-excel","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", // .xls & .xlsx
                "text/plain",
                "application/pdf",
                "application/zip"};

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    intent.setType(mimeTypes.length == 1 ? mimeTypes[0] : "*/*");
    if (mimeTypes.length > 0) {
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
    }
} else {
    String mimeTypesStr = "";
    for (String mimeType : mimeTypes) {
        mimeTypesStr += mimeType + "|";
    }
    intent.setType(mimeTypesStr.substring(0,mimeTypesStr.length() - 1));
}
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"ChooseFile"), REQUEST_CODE_DOC);
```

please note that i am using minimum api 16 so i can't use the open_document intent action

Comment: The best wraparound I did is that I am checking in the onActivityResult method if the data uri contains jpg i ask the user to choose only a word or pdf file and fire a new intent .. but i don't know if it's a proper approach

Comment: "How to prevent user from selecting jpeg or png types from file explorer" -- there is no option for blocking certain MIME types from selection, sorry.